# React list item with icon on Click event

Tags: reactjs

On click of list item want to show checked icon in react. Below is list of items.

[image]

Now on click of any item need to show check icon to understand this menu is clicked/active like below.

[image]

That is need to list item should be present with icon in react js. Below is current code which uis used to list items.

```
 <div key="favorites-dropdown" className={styles.pushBtnDropDown}>
                <ul key="favorites-list">
                  {
                    favorites.map((favorite, idx) => {
                      return (<li key={`favorite-${idx}`}>
                        <a
                          key={`favorite-a-${idx}`}
                          tabIndex={idx}
                          role="button"
                          onClick={() => store.setFavoriteFilters(favorite.reportName, favorite.filters)}
                        >
                          {favorite.name}
                        </a>
                      </li>);
                    })
                  }
                </ul>
              </div>
```

Can someone please help to achieve this output.
Any reference or any another example with code will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create array `favoritesFilters` where you will save all checked filter names and render icons with condition `favoritesFilters.includes(favorite.name)`. Example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
...
const [favoritesFilters, setFavoritesFilters] = useState([]);
const handleFavorites = (favorite) => {
   store.setFavoriteFilters(favorite.reportName, favorite.filters);
   setFavoritesFilters(prev => {
      if(prev.includes(favorite.name)) {
         let newPrev = [...prev];
         return newPrev.filter(item => item !== favorite.name)
      }
      return [...prev, favorite.name]
   })
}
...
<div key="favorites-dropdown" className={styles.pushBtnDropDown}>
            <ul key="favorites-list">
                {
                    favorites.map((favorite, idx) => {
                        return (<li key={`favorite-${idx}`}>
                            //your icon
                            {favoritesFilters.includes(favorite.name) && <img src="your_icon_path" />}
                            <a
                                key={`favorite-a-${idx}`}
                                tabIndex={idx}
                                role="button"
                                onClick={() => handleFavorites(favorite)}
                            >
                                {favorite.name}
                            </a>
                        </li>);
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```